# ButtonDown and ButtonUp using boolean?

Tags: c#, events, input, controller, keypress

so basically I am using a custom controller for input, that sets a boolean value to true as long as a button is held, and false while the button is released.

I need to be able to make an event fire once when the button is first pressed and when it is released.

Does anyone have any advice?

P.S. I am using C# with the .Net Framework.

Edit: How does the .Net Framework achieve keydown and keyup events?

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester be nice..

Comment: what IDE are you using? if you are using Visual Studio you can go to the graphical view and choose Events under Properties.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the winforms button already has such events, for instance the [Click Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click.aspx). If you require to provide them to other parts of your program, you can fire your own event when that triggers.
If you use Visual Studio there is a graphical view where you place your controls. That view also has a properties window which has events (via the lightning icon). Just select your control (the button), go to the events under properties, enter the name of the function that you want triggered when the mouse is down and pass it on

```
public event EventHandler SomethingHappened;
private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    OnSomethingHappened(e);
}

private void OnSomethingHappened(EventArgs args) {
    var handler = SomethingHappened;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, args);
}
```

HTH

Comment: sure, you can just set the boolean value in the OnMouseDown event, if that is what you mean. If not, could you try to expand your question?